# Carrinho de Compras com Agrupamento por Vendedor

Tags: php, mysql

Eu queria agrupar os produtos por vendedores em meu carrinho de compras. Atualmente ele exibe uma lista única, sem essa separação.

#### Exemplo:

Pedro e Maria anunciam em meu site e cada um tem seus produtos oferecidos e quando o cliente clica em comprar produto do Pedro liste em forma de grupo somente os produtos do Pedro e se comprar da Maria listasse também em grupo. Conforme abaixo:

Vendedor(a) (**Pedro**)

```
 *Produto 1     2    R$ 45,00 R$ 90,00
 *Produto 2     1    R$ 25,00 R$ 25,00
Enviar Pedido de Compra
```

Vendedor(a) (**Maria**)

```
 *Produto 1     1    R$ 45,00 R$ 45,00
 *Produto 2     1    R$ 25,00 R$ 25,00
Enviar Pedido de Compra
```

Note que o cliente vai ter que enviar o pedido de compra para os dois compradores.

O carregamento dos produtos eu já fiz, só não estou conseguindo agrupar por vendedores.

A parte da consulta e da exibição do carrinho está abaixo:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $qtd) {
    
    $sql_vendedor = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id='$id'";
    $qr_vendedor = mysql_query($sql_vendedor) or die(mysql_error());
    $ln_vendedor = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr_vendedor);
    $vendedor = $ln_vendedor['vendedor_id'];
    
    $sql = "
    SELECT produtos.id, produtos.nome as descricao,produtos.preco, 
        produtos.imagem, produtos.vendedor_id, vendedores.nome as nomevendedor
    FROM produtos
    INNER JOIN vendedores ON produtos.vendedor_id = vendedores.vendedor_id
    WHERE id='$id' AND produtos.vendedor_id=$vendedor
    GROUP BY " . $vendedor;
    
    $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);
    
    $imagem = $ln['imagem'];
    $nome = $ln['descricao'];
    $preco = number_format($ln['preco'], 2, ',', '.');
    $sub = number_format($ln['preco'] * $qtd, 2, ',', '.');
    $vendedor_id = $ln['vendedor_id'];
    $id_produto = $ln['id'];
    
    $total += $ln['preco'] * $qtd;
    
    $nomevendedor = $ln['nomevendedor'];
    
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="shopping-cart-image">';
    echo '<a href="#"><img src="assets/temp/products/' . $imagem . '" alt="Berry Lace Dress"></a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td class="shopping-cart-description">';
    echo '<h3><a href="#">' . $nome . '</a></h3>';
    echo '<p><strong>Item ' . $id_produto . '</strong> - Colocar mais alguma descrição aqui...</p>';
    echo '<em>Mais Informações</em>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td class="shopping-cart-ref-no">' . $vendedor_id . ' - ' . $nomevendedor . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="shopping-cart-quantity">';
    echo '<div class="product-quantity">';
    echo '<input id="product-quantity" type="text" name="prod[' . $id . ']" value="' . $qtd . '" readonly class="form-control input-sm">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td class="shopping-cart-price">';
    echo '<strong><span>R$ </span>' . $preco . '</strong>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td class="shopping-cart-total">';
    echo '<strong><span>R$ </span>' . $sub . '</strong>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td class="del-goods-col">';
    echo '<a class="del-goods" href="?acao=del&id=' . $id . '"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Não ficou muito claro onde está o problema. É na visualização? Na consulta ao banco?

Comment: Muito obrigado por responder... então, eu consigo trazer os produtos do banco de dados sem erro, porem não estou conseguindo agrupar por vendedor. Queria igual a esta imagem: http://s16.postimg.org/m7snp72bp/Screenshot_8.jpg

Comment: Entendi. Poste a parte que você realiza a consulta ao banco (com o nome dos campos)

Comment: Segue o link para download: http://www.mediafire.com/view/edqx5glxg34946r/codigo.txt

Comment: Eu [editei](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/52610/edit) sua pergunta com parte do código. Quanto mais informações úteis, melhor para o pessoal te ajudar

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo pela forma Lucas....

Answer (score 1):

Vamos desenhar.

Tabela produtos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela vendedores

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

$_SESSION['carrinho']

```
0001=>2
0002=>5
0003=>4
```

Primeiro geramos a lista de ids dos produtos que foram comprados:

```
$itens_comprados = " ";
foreach ($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $qtd) $itens_comprados.= $id.","
$itens_comprados = substr($itens_comprados,0,-1); //pra retirar a virgula do final
```

Agora sim vamos buscar no banco de dados:

```
$sql = "
SELECT produtos.id, produtos.nome as descricao,produtos.preco, 
    produtos.imagem, produtos.vendedor_id, vendedores.nome as nomevendedor
FROM produtos
INNER JOIN vendedores ON produtos.vendedor_id = vendedores.vendedor_id
WHERE id IN ($itens_comprados) order by vendedor_id";
```

Você quer listar todos produtos, não é? Então não há porque usar um group by no SQL porque isso faria com que fosse trazida apenas uma linha por vendedor. No seu caso é melhor ordenar por vendedor.
Depois você trabalha como exibir por vendedor:

```
$vendedor_id = $ln['vendedor_id']; 
$id_produto = $ln['id'];

$vendedor_anterior = ""; 
foreach ($id_produto as $key=>$value){
   $vendedor_atual = $vendedor_id[$key]; 

   if($vendedor_atual!=$vendedor_anterior){ //só imprime se trocar de vendedor 
         //imprime coisas relativos ao vendedor ////////
   }

   /// imprime coisas relativas ao item

   //caso você queira imprimir coisas relativas ao vendedor depois de listar todos os produtos , vc coloca um outro if igual ao de cima aqui

   $vendedor_anterior = $vendedor_atual;

}
```

No meu exemplo ficaria:

Vendedor: Hyoga 
        Prod1: bastao , Quant: 2 
        Prod2: nunchaku, Quant: 5

Vendedor: Naruto 
   Prod1: Sai, Quant: 4